# How to extract a row with a conditon

Tags: pandas

Data frame is below

```
id,validity
1941079,{'NT': 2017-02-10, 'T': None}
326809,None
1935569,{'NT': None, 'T': None}
1932997,{'NT': '2017-02-13', 'T': None}
```

Need to extract the id which `NT` is not None
Expected out is below

`df['not_none]`

```
1941079
1932997
```

Comment: follow this link please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.get`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get.html) with [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filter with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

If necessary convert strings repr to dictionaries use custom function with `try-except`:

```
import ast

def parse_to_dict(x):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(x)
    except:
        return None

df['validity'] = df['validity'].apply(parse_to_dict)

s = df.loc[df['validity'].str.get('NT').notna(), 'id']
print (s)
0    1941079
3    1932997
Name: id, dtype: int64
```